# Solving the linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, factoring

Here we have a linear differential equation with constant coefficients:

> $$ (D^4 + 2D^3 + 3D^2 + 2D + 1)y = 0 $$

while I know how to solve the differential equations of these type,my problem is rather simple , I am not able to factorize the given f(D) in the auxiliary equation.

Comment: **Hint:** $$(m^2 + m + 1)^2 = 0$$ Find these roots to solve the problem.

Comment: @Moo ok thanks,  got it